# Python String move places

Tags: python

I have in csv file row with pictures like:

```
MAXTON_6738_10.png|MAXTON_6738_6.jpg|MAXTON_6738_9.jpg|MAXTON_6738_7.jpg|MAXTON_6738_2.jpg|MAXTON_6738_3.jpg|MAXTON_6738_4.jpg|MAXTON_6738_11.jpg
```

I need to change places of first and second pictures. like:

```
MAXTON_6738_6.jpg|MAXTON_6738_10.png|MAXTON_6738_9.jpg|MAXTON_6738_7.jpg|MAXTON_6738_2.jpg|MAXTON_6738_3.jpg|MAXTON_6738_4.jpg|MAXTON_6738_11.jpg
```

I dont know how i can avoid spliting it to array and convert back to string

EDIT:

```
str="MAXTON_6738_10.png|MAXTON_6738_6.jpg|MAXTON_6738_9.jpg|MAXTON_6738_7.jpg|MAXTON_6738_2.jpg|MAXTON_6738_3.jpg|MAXTON_6738_4.jpg|MAXTON_6738_11.jpg"
array = str.split("|")
second=array[1]
array[1]=array[0]
array[0]=second
new=my_string = '|'.join(array)
```

Comment: Why are you concerned about splitting and converting back into a string?

Comment: Do split into a list, swap it, turn it back into a string. Why would you want to avoid that?

Comment: `parts=row.split("|");parts[0:2]=parts[0:2][::-1];row="|".join(parts)` I don't see any reason why avoid splitting, it's faster than the file reading anyways

Comment: I Edit. I just write larger code ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable. You cannot change a character or subset of characters without writing over the whole variable. I suppose you're trying to save space for a seemingly simple task? You can write to the same variable like this:

```
row = row.split("|")
row.insert(0, row.pop(1))
row = "|".join(row)
```